# Command 'CCDX: Deploy Source To Salesforce' resulted in an error (Cannot read property 'path' of undefined)

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, lwc-dev-server

Facing below error when I am trying to deploy LWC from VS Code

*Command 'CCDX: Deploy Source To Salesforce' resulted in an error (Cannot read property 'path' of undefined)*

Steps to generate error:

1. Create LWC in Scratch Org.
2. Authorize Dev Hub.
3. Use SFDX: Deploy this Source to Org from the "Ctrl+Shift+P" Command Palette in VS Code to deploy LWC project files.

Please help!

Comment: I'm using an additional companion extension.

Comment: what plugins do you have? Can you run sfdx plugins ?

Comment: I recommend you use SFDX: Deploy Source To Salesforce an SFDX command than CCDX! CCDX was meant only if you enable autosave